# In general, how do you construct a nontrivial representation of a group?

Tags: representation-theory

This is my first time studying representations. I'm not sure how to go about constructing a nontrivial representation of a group. Do I construct a function that satisfies the definition? Could you provide an arbitrary example?

Comment: FYI, here is an [example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupRepresentation.html)

Comment: Every group has a [regular representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation), which is nontrivial so long as the group is nontrivial.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on mt_'s comment, one can more generally construct representations of $G$ on function spaces, by which I mean a vector space $V$ consisting of functions (lying in some appropriate class -- finitely supported, continuous, square-integrable, smooth, tempered, etc) $f:G\rightarrow W$, where $W$ is a vector space over some field $k$. Then the space $V$ carries two natural actions of $G$ by left and right translation:
$$(g\cdot f)(x)=f(gx)$$
and
$$(g\cdot f)(x)=f(xg^{-1}).$$
Obviously, you need $V$ to consist of functions such that their image under the action of $G$ also lies in $V$, but in practice there are plenty of such spaces.

This turns $V$ into a representation of $G$ over the field $k$.